# Taking picture result in a distorted image

Tags: android

I'm using the the Android SDK sample to get an image from the camera. The code below is the only logic I added to the code. Essentially I'm taking the picture converting it to a bitmap and displaying it. Unfortunately this results on a real phone as a distorted image (on the emulator it is just fine)

Any help will be appreciated

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null,new PictureCallback(){

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                    showPicture(data);
                }

            });
            break;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

void showPicture(byte[] data) {

    if (data != null) {
        Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory
                .decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
        view.setImageBitmap(picture);
        this.setContentView(view);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem in the surfaceChanged method these lines are to blame

`List sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        if (sizes != null) {
            Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, width, height);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
        } else {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
        }`

Removing them solved all the issue. Now I'll have to make sure that this won't cause new problems


BTW

This Happens on a G2